# How to access query path properties in a resolver? GraphQL

Tags: graphql

I have a database with the following structure.

[image: Graph Database]
I'm writing a GraphQL resolver for the bottom-most node (the "rows" node).

As the image shows, each "rows" node corresponds to a specific path. (Company)->(DB)->(Table)->(rows)

A Query would be of the form:

```
{
  Company(name: "Google") {
    Database(name: "accounts") {
      Table(name: "users") {
        rows
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Question:** How can I include/access `Company.name`, `Database.name`, `Table.name` information in the `rows` resolver so that I can determine which `rows` node to return?

In other words: I know I can access `Table.name` using `parent.name`, but is there a way to get `parent.parent.name` or `parent.parent.parent.name`?

If there isn't a way to access ancestor properties, should I use arguments or context to pass these properties manually into the `rows` resolver?

Note: I can't use the neo4j-graphql-js package.

Note: This is the first simple example I thought of and I understand there are structural problems with organizing data this way, but the question still stands.

Comment: Not sure if this is what you're after: https://graphql.org/graphql-js/passing-arguments/ another article with a clearer explanation: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphql-tools/resolvers/ (`args: An object with the arguments passed into the field in the query. For example, if the field was called with author(name: "Ada"), the args object would be: { "name": "Ada" }.`

Comment: @nopassport1 I know I could use arguments, but the problem with this is that I would be defining the query path twice: once as the normal GraphQL query (like the one posted in my question), and again as an argument for ```rows```. Thank you either way, I'll make my question more specific.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can extract the path from the GraphQLResolveInfo object passed to the resolver:

```
const { responsePathAsArray } = require('graphql')

function resolver (parent, args, context, info) {
  responsePathAsArray(info.path)
}
```

This returns an array like `['google', 'accounts', 0, 'user']`. However, you can also pass arbitrary data from parent resolver to child resolver.

```
function accountResolver (parent, args, context, info) {
  // Assuming we already have some value at parent.account and want to return that
  return {
    ...parent.account,
    message: 'It\'s a secret!',
  }
}

function userResolver (parent, args, context, info) {
  console.log(parent.message) // prints "It's a secret!"
}
```

Unless `message` matches some field name, it won't ever actually appear in your response.